# Data Encoding to create handle to a population collection

Tags: serialization, enumeration

A fictional Broadway show has 3 shows every Saturday. Tickets are valid for a particular show and enumerated seat. The process of encoding the `showtime` and serially enumerated `seat number` defines a **unique** ticket.   Ticket are encoded with a barcode comprising said data to measure attendance.

Is the process of encoding the notion of a time and seat an example serialization? enumeration? If not, what should it be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization has to me two meanings:
1. Some operation is serialized, i.e. executed sequentially, in contrast to concurrently.
2. Some data structure is transformed in a format that can be stored e.g. in a file.
Enumeration means to me
3. a data type for variables that can accept a finite number of values.

Encoding the notion of a time and seat is thus for me an example of 2., since one had only to store the date, the show, and the seat, which is unique.

But it is also an example of 3., assuming the following:
An `enum` is encoded as 64 bits, i.e. the maximum is 2^64, i.e roughly 10^21. The question is now, how long the earth will live.
One assumes that our sun will become a red giant in about 5 billion years, and extinct all life on earth. Thus, 5 billion years = 5 * 10^9 years = 52 weeks / year * 5 * 10^9 years, which is about 250 * 10^9 saturdays.
With 3 shows / saturdays this is about 10^12 shows until the end of the earth.
But the `enum` could encode 10^21 shows, so no problem for encoding...